# Japanese characters not showing properly

Tags: multi-language

I've run into a problem that I'm not quite sure how to fix. I have a website that is partly in English and partly in Japanese. It all worked perfectly until a few hours ago, when I decided to change a font. When I changed the font, all the Japanese characters on my index page turned into gibberish, while working perfectly in the posts and in the archives. I have no idea how to fix this problem. I reverted the changes but it still doesn't work.

I have:
-Cleared the cache
-Tried on multiple devicee and browsers

Interestingly, every time I clear the cache, the first time I refresh the page, it works. But after that, it stops working.

Any ideas on how to solve this? Help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Without knowing exactly what you did and seeing what is happening, it is unlikely that anyone will be able to help you.

Comment: As Milo mentioned, please provide more information, codes, and possibly a link to your website if it is not under maintenance.

Comment: I apologize for not providing enough info. However, I literally only changed a font and all japanese characters turned into gibberish. I fixed it by disabling the page cache in the W3 cache plugin, so I believe that to be the cause of the problem. I guess I should just start by deactivating plugins whenever I run into a problem.